# MySQL keeps dying for no apparent reason

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql

I'm looking after a VPS with the following specifications: Centos 6, 50GB HDD & 512MB memory.

The problem I'm having is MySQL keeps on crashing for no apparent reason. I've double checked the log files and here's what I'm seeing:

```
Version: '5.1.71'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
140217 15:12:40 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140217 15:12:40 [Warning] option 'thread_stack': unsigned value 65536 adjusted to 131072
140217 15:12:40  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140217 15:12:40  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140217 15:12:40  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140217 15:12:41  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1613784
140217 15:12:41 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140217 15:12:41 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.71'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

When I go to reboot the service, it returns "Another MySQL daemon already running with the same unix socket.". To get around this I've simply been renaming/removing the sock file. The MySQL server starts up but within a few hours or days it crashes again.

Any recommendations on how to debug or resolve this issue? Could it be related to memory usage?

Comment: To see memory usage, type in your shell the command : "mysql_report". I suggest to look for corruption problems. Run the mysqlcheck --all-databases to see if you have corrupted tables. Then look for hardware problems like memory or disk. Because you have a VPS, is your data partition not mounted by another system ??? It could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Here is what top is reporting: VIRT=681m, RES=20m, CPU%=0.0, MEM%=4.2 (taking into consideration that it has just been restarted). I'll check the other bits now.

Comment: mysqlcheck returned: mysql.general_log
Error    : You can't use locks with log tables.
status   : OK

mysql.slow_log
Error    : You can't use locks with log tables.
status   : OK

Comment: Check your server's general logs (e.g. `/var/log/messages`)

Comment: I've just created and looked in a MySQL "slow queries" log file and there's one in there which lasted over 14 seconds. I'm guessing that needs to be addressed? With regards to the server's messages log file, what should I be looking for? There's already 1,500 lines for today!